# Row wise merge comma separated values in a `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table, paste, strsplit

I have a `data.table` `DT` as follows.

```
DT <- structure(list(ID = c("Bats", "HL", "JL", "Spidey", "Supes", 
"X"), List1 = c("Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb", "David, Bryne, Lee", 
"", "Loeb, Lee", "Moore, Siegel, Millar", "Bendis, Whendon"), 
    List2 = c("Rucka, Kane, Morrison", "Lee, Mantlo, Bryne", 
    "Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison", "Waid, Yost, Kirby, Lee", 
    "", "Claremont, Whendon, Morrison")), .Names = c("ID", "List1", 
"List2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = NULL, sorted = "ID")
```

DT

```
      ID                            List1                        List2
1:   Bats Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb        Rucka, Kane, Morrison
2:     HL                David, Bryne, Lee           Lee, Mantlo, Bryne
3:     JL                                   Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
4: Spidey                        Loeb, Lee       Waid, Yost, Kirby, Lee
5:  Supes            Moore, Siegel, Millar                             
6:      X                  Bendis, Whendon Claremont, Whendon, Morrison
```

I would like to merge the two lists row-wise in columns `DT$List1` and `DT$List2` together without duplicates.

I can do this with `apply` as follows.

```
DT$merged <- apply(DT,1,function(vec){
  paste(unique(strsplit(paste(vec[2],vec[3],sep=", "),", ")[[1]]),collapse=", ")
})

     DT
       ID                            List1                        List2
1:   Bats Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb        Rucka, Kane, Morrison
2:     HL                David, Bryne, Lee           Lee, Mantlo, Bryne
3:     JL                                   Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
4: Spidey                        Loeb, Lee       Waid, Yost, Kirby, Lee
5:  Supes            Moore, Siegel, Millar                             
6:      X                  Bendis, Whendon Claremont, Whendon, Morrison
                                          merged
1: Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb, Rucka, Kane
2:                     David, Bryne, Lee, Mantlo
3:                 , Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
4:                  Loeb, Lee, Waid, Yost, Kirby
5:                         Moore, Siegel, Millar
6:          Bendis, Whendon, Claremont, Morrison
```

How to get the same result efficiently with `data.table` without the ", " in beginning and end due to empty cells?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way to do this using paste, but you could always wrap this in an if-then statement, where if both columns have values you use that function, but if only one column has a value you simply use the data from that column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DT[, merged := toString(unique(c(strsplit(List1, split = ", ")[[1]],
                                 strsplit(List2, split = ", ")[[1]]))), by = ID][]
#       ID                            List1                        List2
#1:   Bats Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb        Rucka, Kane, Morrison
#2:     HL                David, Bryne, Lee           Lee, Mantlo, Bryne
#3:     JL                                   Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
#4: Spidey                        Loeb, Lee       Waid, Yost, Kirby, Lee
#5:  Supes            Moore, Siegel, Millar                             
#6:      X                  Bendis, Whendon Claremont, Whendon, Morrison
#                                          merged
#1: Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb, Rucka, Kane
#2:                     David, Bryne, Lee, Mantlo
#3:                   Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
#4:                  Loeb, Lee, Waid, Yost, Kirby
#5:                         Moore, Siegel, Millar
#6:          Bendis, Whendon, Claremont, Morrison
```

Or replace the 'by' with `1:nrow(DT)` if your `ID` column is not unique.

Comment: In place of `unique(c(x,y))`, `union(x,y)` seems to work. Here's that, using `.SD`: `DT[,merged := toString(Reduce(union,lapply(.SD,function(x) strsplit(x,split=", ")[[1]]))), by = ID][]`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
DT[, merged := do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep=", ")), .SDcols= List1:List2
 ][, merged:=unlist(lapply(strsplit(merged, ", "),
          function(x)  toString(unique(x))))]   
#     ID                            List1                        List2
#1:   Bats Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb        Rucka, Kane, Morrison
#2:     HL                David, Bryne, Lee           Lee, Mantlo, Bryne
#3:     JL                                   Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
#4: Spidey                        Loeb, Lee       Waid, Yost, Kirby, Lee
#5:  Supes            Moore, Siegel, Millar                             
#6:      X                  Bendis, Whendon Claremont, Whendon, Morrison
#                                          merged
#1: Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb, Rucka, Kane
#2:                     David, Bryne, Lee, Mantlo
#3:                 , Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
#4:                  Loeb, Lee, Waid, Yost, Kirby
#5:                         Moore, Siegel, Millar
#6:          Bendis, Whendon, Claremont, Morrison
```

Or we could use `regex` after `do.call(paste` to remove the duplicate elements

```
 DT[, merged := gsub('^,\\s*|(\\b\\S+\\b)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b.*),\\s*|,\\s*$', '',
     do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep=", ")), perl=TRUE), .SDcols = List1:List2]
#   ID                            List1                        List2
#1:   Bats Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb        Rucka, Kane, Morrison
#2:     HL                David, Bryne, Lee           Lee, Mantlo, Bryne
#3:     JL                                   Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
#4: Spidey                        Loeb, Lee       Waid, Yost, Kirby, Lee
#5:  Supes            Moore, Siegel, Millar                             
#6:      X                  Bendis, Whendon Claremont, Whendon, Morrison
 #                                         merged
#1: Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb, Rucka, Kane, Morrison
#2:                     David, Lee, Mantlo, Bryne
#3:                   Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
#4:                  Loeb, Waid, Yost, Kirby, Lee
#5:                         Moore, Siegel, Millar
#6:          Bendis, Claremont, Whendon, Morrison
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be another way

```
DT[, merged:= paste(union(unlist(strsplit(List1, ', ')),
              unlist(strsplit(List2, ', '))), collapse = ', '), by = ID]

#> DT
#       ID                            List1                        List2
#1:   Bats Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb        Rucka, Kane, Morrison
#2:     HL                David, Bryne, Lee           Lee, Mantlo, Bryne
#3:     JL                                   Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
#4: Spidey                        Loeb, Lee       Waid, Yost, Kirby, Lee
#5:  Supes            Moore, Siegel, Millar                             
#6:      X                  Bendis, Whendon Claremont, Whendon, Morrison
#                                          merged
#1: Morrison, Brubaker, Daniel, Loeb, Rucka, Kane
#2:                     David, Bryne, Lee, Mantlo
#3:                   Meltzer, Sekowsky, Morrison
#4:                  Loeb, Lee, Waid, Yost, Kirby
#5:                         Moore, Siegel, Millar
#6:          Bendis, Whendon, Claremont, Morrison
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example to show another approach. The function `trimComma` just trims off the the commas at beginning and at the end. It also trims repeating commas and can easily be used with `paste`

```
trimComma <-function(x)
{
    gsub(",,",",",gsub("^,+|,+$|","",x))
}
```